# How to add custom headers in aws application loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-application-load-balancer

I have my application running on multiple AWS EC2 instances under an AWS Application Load Balancer. An Nginx web server is installed on these EC2 instances to serve website contents. However, when I add the following headers in the NGINX configuration, the changes are not reflected.

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
```

Can anyone help me understand why the above Nginx changes are not reflecting? I am checking the changes on https://securityheaders.com/.

Comment: ALB should not drop HTTP headers by itself. Do you have a CloudFront distribution or another CDN in front of ALB?

Comment: No I don't have

Answer (score 1):

Working with ALB you can easly create custom headers, start with x-[your-header] its will work, remember your application should accept it to, i will recommend to print out your full header inside your application so you can see the headers working.

When you hit your nginx server its sound forward the header down to your application to, so i will start to hit a single application dircly before your proxy it down to your application to troubleshoot your problem faster.